# No Instragram photos when accessing 'explore/locations'

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to build a webpage which shows all the public Instagram photos of this location:
https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/213827561/strokkur-geysir/

So I logged into Instagram, I create a client in the Developers Section, I obtained the 'client_id', and then I managed to obtain the access_token with 'response_type=token' and 'scope=public_content'.

However, I try to access this petition:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/213827561?access_token=xxx
and I get the following data:

> {"data": {"id": "213827561", "name": "Strokkur - Geysir", "latitude":
>   64.146178476129, "longitude": -21.93411316583}, "meta": {"code": 200}}

There is no information about all the photos I can see in 
https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/213827561/strokkur-geysir/
and some of that photos are mine.

I expected to obtain data of, at least, my photos, but no photos are shown. I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: are you in sandbox mode, if so, you will not see any data except your's or your sandbox user's posts in response, once u go live, you will see all data

Comment: The problem is that I can not see either my own photos.

Comment: do u have the same location id tagged to your photo ?